# How does difficulty work in Puzzle Quest?

Tags: puzzle-quest

What exactly is changed in the game engine when I change, say, from 'Normal' to 'Easy'?

Does it influence spell research minigame?

Comment: This question is too vague.  Please clarify or close the question.

Comment: Edited. I still predict that the original form will become a standard here.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the fact that a question has to be well-worded. I still don't really understand what's asked here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done some research, and as far as I can tell, the difficulty only determines how hard it is to beat the computer opponents. It has nothing to do with the spell research.